# Minimal intervals between jobs

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve a problem of minimizing the sum of time intervals between jobs that are given in an array. The structure of the job is as follows:

```
struct Job{ int start, end; };
```

and the prototype of function is:

```
int impatientBob(Job jobs[], int n, int k)
```

Jobs can't overlap and I have to choose k of them from array or return -1 if it's impossible. Furthermore, the array is sorted by the ending time of jobs and time is given in minutes. 
I don't have any good idea, because I'm still quite new to dynamic programming.

Comment: If by "time intervals between jobs", you mean the idle periods where no job is running because you are waiting for an available job to arrive, the O(n lg n) Longest-Available-Job algorithm should be optimal. That algorithm will avoid idle periods altogether when possible. (Or am I confusing a hard starting requirement with an arrival time?)

Comment: Yes, it is about minimizing sum of the all idle periods. Could you elaborate on that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I can think of is with complexity `O(n^2 * k)`.

You can do something like that (the following is just a pseudocode):

```
int minTimeIntervals(current_index, last_taken, k){
    if(k == 0) return 0 // if you already taken k jobs then you're done
    if(current_index == n) return BIG NUMBER // if you reached the end of the jobs without taking k jobs, then this is an invalid solution. Set it to a big number so when you minimize it's always neglected.

    check if the given state is memorized and has been calculated before.

    decision1 = minTimeIntervals(current_index + 1, last_taken, k) // Choose not to take the current job and move to the next.
    if(start time of current job > end time of last taken job){
        // Choose to take the current job of that's valid (i.e they don't intersect)
        decision2 = minTimeIntervals(current_index + 1, current_index, k-1) + difference of time between last_taken and current_index
    }
    return minimum of decision1 and decision2 and memorize the answer for the given state.
}
```

EDIT: Adding more concrete code.

```
int memo[N][N][K]; // Should be initialized with -1

int minTimeIntervals(int current_index, int last_taken, int k){
    if(k == 0) return 0;
    if(current_index == N) return 1<<27; // 2^27, Just a big number.

    if(last_taken != -1 && memo[current_index][last_taken][k] != -1) return memo[current_index][last_taken][k];

    int decision1 = minTimeIntervals(current_index + 1, last_taken, k);
    int decision2 = 1<<27;
    if(last_taken == -1 || jobs[current_index].start >= jobs[last_taken].end){
        decision2 = minTimeIntervals(current_index + 1, current_index, k - 1) + (jobs[current_index].start - jobs[last_taken].end);
    }
    int result = min(decision1, decision2);
    memo[current_index][last_taken][k] = result;
    return result;
}
```

What this code is doing is that for a given state `(current_index, last_taken, k)`, it calculates the answer and store it in `memo[current_index][last_taken][k]`.

The array memo should be initialized with some value that can never be a valid answer (e.g. -1). Now if the value `memo[i][j][k]` is -1 that means that we haven't computed the state (i,j,k) before, so we compute it and store it in `memo[i][j][k]`.

If for some given state (i,j,k) the value in `memo[i][j][k]` was some non-negative value (say 5), it means that we processed this state before and the answer was 5 so just return this answer without repeating the calculations.

The last tricky part is that when you pick your first job, you don't have a previous job to calculate the time difference. For that we set last_taken to be -1 so we know that this is the first job and we don't have to calculate the time difference between current_index and last_taken.

Now your main function `impatientBob` should do some initialization work like setting `memo` values to -1, then call the function `minTimeIntervals(0, -1, k)` which means that you're starting from the first job, you haven't taken any previous jobs before, and you still need to take k jobs.

Comment: Thank you very much for that algorithm. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if you have any questions or problems with implementing that.

Comment: Yes, I have a question. Should I use two-dimensional array for memorizing consecutive sums?

Comment: Typically you'll use the same number of states as dimensions. In this case if you memorize in an array called m, then you do something like m[current_index][last_taken][k] = result.
I don't know much about the problem size and whether this is taking too much memory or not. There are tricks though to reduce the memory size if needed.

Comment: Would you help me to implement that? I still don't get it.

Comment: First, do you have constraints on the input size? Is O(n^2 * k) sufficient for you?

Comment: Yes, O(n^2 * k) is completely sufficient for me.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help, but I still don't understand the use of three-dimensional array here. Is that necessary? My other question is, if we can solve that problem without recursion.